# Declaring an array with incremental values in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, shortcut

I know it's possible to declare an array like this:

```
my @array = ( 5 .. 10 );
```

which is equivalent to:

```
my @array = ( 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 );
```

but is there a similar shorthand when the incremental value is greater than one e.g.

```
my @array = ( 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 );
my @array = ( 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 );
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
my @array = map 5*$_, 1..5;
```

and

```
my @array = map 100*$_, 1..5;
```

Comment: `"my" variable @array masks earlier declaration in same scope` :)

Comment: @DVK, Two separate examples, just like in the OP

Comment: @ikegami - I know, I was being sarcastic. I edited to remove any possible doubt that they are separate examples

Comment: @DVK I know I’m in the minority here, but I still think it is preferable to use and read the `{}` version, `map { 100 * $_ } 1..5`, because you don’t expect the code block to be evaluated before the function is called, whereas when merely the first parameter in a comma-separated list of arguments of a function call, you certainly do. Yes, I know it costs you a block setup. I don’t care because I find it more readable and less confusing the other way, which is always more important than premature micro-optimization. I also hold some wan hope that this shall someday be optimized in the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

More generally:

```
my $start = 5;
my $stop = 25;
my $increment = 5;
my @array = map $start+$increment*$_, 0..($stop-$start)/$increment;
```

or:

```
chomp(my @array = `seq $start $increment $stop`);
```

(Just kidding.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Damian Conway's [List::Maker](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aMaker).

```
use List::Maker;
my @list = <0..100 x 5>;
```